# Prevent touchmove default (browser scrolling) until condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

The objective is to have a component, in this case a carousel, that responds to the touchmove event when the user is moving his finger from left to right, but does not prevent the default scrolling up and down, even if the touch originates on the component in question, provided the user moves his finger on the y axis beyond a certain threshold.

Or, more plainly, I need to disable the browser scroll on touch devices, until the touchmove even says its OK, and re-enables it.

Despite several hours of tinkering, I've only been able to disable browser scroll completely or not disable it all. Conditionally disabling does not seem to want to work.

The basic logic is:

1. Record the coordinates on finger down (touch start).
2. On touchmove, check to see if the Y difference is greater than 200px.
3. If so, allow the default of browser scrolling, disable the touchmove listener.
4. If not, prevent the default of scrolling, scroll left/right.

I've been testing this on a late edition iPad mini. I have discovered the following:

1. Calling preventDefault() in the touchstart handler stops all browser scrolling for that touch, it cannot be re-enabled during drag.
2. Trying to conditionally prevent default in the dragmove handler behaves the same as preventDefault in the touchstart handler. That is, it blocks the drag, and ignores the condition!

A condition like this in dragmove:

```
if(Math.abs(MouseMoveDistanceY) < 200){
   if(ev.preventDefault){ev.preventDefault();}
}
```

...blocks vertical scrolling permanently, even if the threshold gets exceeded!

In any case, how can I, on touch devices and in the dragmove handler, surrender control to the browser scroll when a condition is met? Something like "unPreventDefault()" would be great. Barring that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, as I can't give you a direct answer so this is more of just looking at a different approach.. but have you looked at changing the page so that there is nothing to actually scroll when on the touch event? ie/ fix the height and add in overflow hidden.

Comment: according to you ,if it is not an answer ,you could've put this in comment section

Comment: Sorry, have only just started using this and didn't see the comments. Just tried to move it and can't comment yet anyway.